# Google Tag Manager mobile variables corrupted

Tags: ios, mobile, google-tag-manager

When I create a user-defined variable I have problems with the JSON formatting

```
{
"banner": {
    "bannerAdsEnabled": true,
    "bannerAdLocationTop": false
},
"interstitial": {
    "interstitialAdsEnabled": true,
    "maxInterstitialsPerDay": 10,
}}
```

When I do it this way I always get

> GoogleTagManager error: Invalid macro:
>   GoogleTagManager error: Failed to parse an invalid boolean:

The only solution I found is to format my variable as follows:

```
{
  "bannerAdsEnabled": true,
  "bannerAdLocationTop": false,
  "interstitialAdsEnabled": true,
  "maxInterstitialsPerDay": 10 }
```

I a [video from Google I/O '13](https://youtu.be/Xe8W5w68BRg?t=364) the guy is formatting the the way I want to do it and it is working. What am I doing wrong?